# double array to sent from TCP client

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, sockets, tcp

in this days I'm working on a TCP communication between to computers, I would send an array composed by 6 double elements. Usually I used the function send, that accept a char* that has to be send. Is possible with the same function send this array.

thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2):

The `send` function accepts `char *`  because of tradition, because `char` used to be the same as a byte, so passing a `char *` argument is the same as passing a pointer to a series of bytes.

It should be safe to cast any pointer to `char *` when calling e.g. `send`.

It's however *not* guaranteed that the receiving end will receive what you expect. The floating point format could be different on the two systems or there could be byte-ordering issues.

Comment: thank you for your answer. so the are other ways to send the array through a socket connection without using the function send?